# export to pdf using itextsharp

Tags: itext, stringbuilder

I have a .aspx page in which I have a panel and some controls and one gridview. I am trying to take the print of that panel, but the downloaded pdf is empty. I don't  know why, could someone explain me?

Here's the code I was trying

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=UserDetails.pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
this.pnlprint.RenderControl(hw);
StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
pdfDoc.Open();
htmlparser.Parse(sr);
pdfDoc.Close();
Response.Write(pdfDoc);
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your:

```
Response.Write(pdfDoc);
```

to:

```
Response.BinaryWrite(pdfDoc.ToArray());
```